# Implementing a groupBy extension for Kotlin Flow

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-flow

I have a flow like this: `Flow<List<Transaction>>`

Each `Transaction` object has a `Category` object

What i want is an extension function that groups the transactions per `Category`

This is what i've tried:

```
inline fun <T, K> Flow<Iterable<T>>.groupIterableBy(crossinline keySelector: (T) -> K): Flow<Map<K, MutableList<T>>> = map {
        val storage = HashMap<K, MutableList<T>>()
        it.map{ element ->
            val key = keySelector(element)
            if (storage[key] == null){
                storage[key] = mutableListOf()
            }
            storage[key]!!.add(element)
        }
        return@map storage
}
```

This works great, but i don't feel like this is programmed in a clean way.
**Does anyone have suggestions for making this function cleaner?**

Comment: `= map { it.groupBy(keySelector) }` ?

Comment: haha i'm shocked that i overcomplicated it so much. Thanks this is much better!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following IR42's comment, this should work. Why not use

```
Iterable.groupBy()
```

Example scratch:

```
data class Tra(
    val cat: Cat
)

data class Cat(
    val name: String
)

val flow = flowOf(
    listOf(
        Tra(Cat("A")),
        Tra(Cat("B")),
        Tra(Cat("D")),
        Tra(Cat("B"))
    ),
    listOf(
        Tra(Cat("A")),
        Tra(Cat("C")),
        Tra(Cat("B")),
        Tra(Cat("A")),
        Tra(Cat("C"))
    )
)

inline fun <T, K> Flow<Iterable<T>>.groupIterableBy(crossinline  keySelector: (T) -> K): Flow<Map<K, List<T>>> =
    map { it.groupBy(keySelector) }

val groupedFlow = flow.groupIterableBy{it.cat.name}

runBlocking {
    groupedFlow
        .collect {
            println(it)
        }
}
```

It prints:

```
{A=[Tra(cat=Cat(name=A))], B=[Tra(cat=Cat(name=B)), Tra(cat=Cat(name=B))], D=[Tra(cat=Cat(name=D))]}
{A=[Tra(cat=Cat(name=A)), Tra(cat=Cat(name=A))], C=[Tra(cat=Cat(name=C)), Tra(cat=Cat(name=C))], B=[Tra(cat=Cat(name=B))]}
```

Is this the result you're looking for?

Comment: Depending on your downstream operations, you can also consider playing with goupingBy() from the standard library. GoupingBy is lazy, and might be more complementary to the cold nature of Flow.
https://kotlinlang.org/docs/collection-grouping.html